# How do I retrieve historical currency exchanges rates (USDEUR) in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates, google-finance

I am not quite sure how to get historical exchange rates from Google Sheets. It is the start date and number of days, daily/weekly that is confusing to me. I was able to get the current exchange rate, but I want different rates for the date I am referencing. I also tried replacing `"12/13/2021"` with `date(2021,12,13)` but that was not successful either.

`=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDEUR",,"12/13/2021",1,"DAILY")*5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
`=GoogleFinance("Currency:USDEUR", "Close", date(2021,12,13), 1)`

Alternatively, you can specify parameters in cells and reference the formula accordingly.

This is an example, based on the screenshot below:

`=GoogleFinance($B$2&":"&$B$3&$B$4, $B$5, $B$6, $B$7)`

---

**Sample**

[image: screenshot]

The examples included under "Exchange Rate Trends" in the [Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281) are helpful.

Comment: That is better. I was able to reference a date field using your second example, but it takes up more than 1 cell. I think there's an INDEX function I can try using just to get the closing rate.

Comment: `index(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EURUSD","CLOSE",DATE(2021,12,18),1),2,2)` worked for me.